# How to make a v-for loop of DIVs and show them by part (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row" >
        <div v-for="(result,i) in results" :key="i" class="col-sm-6" >
            <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light" >
                <div class="card-header text-center" > {{ result.title }} </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
                    <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc" ></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
                    <a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" @click="getData(i)" >Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to parse these `col-sm-6` divs generated by a v-for loop (Vue.js).The goal is to make them visible 5 by 5.First they have to be all invisible -> event handler -> 5 visible -> event handler -> 10 visible and so on...
And I think I need to parse them.The `{{result.title}}` and `result.prevDesc` are perfectly working,no worries about that.

Comment: what's your purpose? it could be done in other way

Comment: Nice to see you again Brahim,as I said,my purpose is to parse them using a for and depending on an if condition make  5 of them invisible or not.For every div i check it's data and if i don't like it it will be invisible else visible

Comment: could you show some results array content ?

Comment: result = { 1 : { title : Title1 , prevDesc : description1 }, 
           2 : { title : Title2 , prevDesc : description2 }, 
           3 : { title : Title3 , prevDesc : description3 } 
         }
For example

Comment: which condition you want to use in order to show/hide a div ? i mean something like `v-if=""title=="title2"`

Comment: It doesn't matter while it works and is doing what I mentioned above.

Comment: yes, i understand that you want to : initially the results are hidden whene you click on a button it shows 5 and if you click again it shows 10 ...

Comment: Yes,that's it..

Comment: please approve or reject the waiting edit to let me edit your question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep your `results` array and create another one called `shownResults` that doesn't contain initially any result, but when you click `showMore` button you will have 5 results pushed to that array and shown, if you click again you'll have 10 results shown and so on,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    bound:0,
       results:[
       {
       title:"title1",
       prevDesc:"desc1"
       },
        {
       title:"title2",
       prevDesc:"desc2"
       },
         {
       title:"title3",
       prevDesc:"desc3"
       },
         {
       title:"title4",
       prevDesc:"desc4"
       },
         {
       title:"title5",
       prevDesc:"desc5"
       },
         {
       title:"title7",
       prevDesc:"desc7"
       },
         {
       title:"title8",
       prevDesc:"desc8"
       }
       ],
       shownResults:[]
       } 
  },
  methods:{
  showMore(){
  this.bound+=5;
     this.shownResults=this.results.slice(0,this.bound);
  },
    getData(i){
    
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div id="app">
<div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp" >
 <div class="row" >
    <div v-for="(result,i) in shownResults" :key="i" class="col-sm-6" >
      <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light" >
         <div class="card-header text-center" > {{ result.title }} </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc" ></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" @click="getData(i)" >Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="height:40px" @click="showMore" >Show more</a>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a cool solution, you could also do it using `computed` properties